# opendir() with pagination support

Tags: php, pagination

I have this script:

```
<?php
if ($handle = opendir('konten')) {
    $blacklist = array('.', '..', 'somedir', 'index.php', 'style.css');
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) :
        if (!in_array($file, $blacklist)) :

?>
<div style="display:block;clear:both;">
<span style="font-size:18px;">&raquo;</span> <a href=""><?php echo $file;?></a>
</div>
<?php
endif;
endwhile;
closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

The output looks like this:

```
» linux (5th copy)
» linux
» linux (10th copy)
» linux (9th copy)
» linux (4th copy)
» linux (6th copy)
» linux (8th copy)
» linux (copy)
» linux (7th copy)
» linux (another copy)
» linux (3rd copy)
```

How to add pagination to it?
e.g.:
I want to display only 3 dirs on one page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you need to set limit and page like follows:

But in this case you will get almost all files in directory.

```
<?php
$limit = 4; //Or just for dynamic limit - (int)$_GET['limit'];
$page = (int)$_GET['page']?:0; // _GET['page'] or 0 for default
$skip = $limit * $page;
if ($handle = opendir('konten')) {
    $blacklist = array('.', '..', 'somedir', 'index.php', 'style.css');
    $skiped = 0;
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if (!in_array($file, $blacklist)) { 
        $skipped++;
        if ($skipped < $skip || $skipped >= $skip + $limit) {
            continue;
        }
        ?>
            <div style="display:block;clear:both;">
                 <span style="font-size:18px;">&raquo;</span> <a href=""><?php echo $file;?></a>
             </div>           
       <?php }
    }
}
// For pagination support
$pages = (int)$skipped / $limit;
if ($skipped % $limit)
    $pages ++;

for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
     $class = '';
     if ($page == $i) $class = 'class="active"';
    ?> <a href="?page=<?= $i ?>" <?= $class ?>><?= $i ?></a> <?php
}
?>
```

UPD: Added pagination support

Comment: thats work if i set url to ?limit=4&page=1 for example. but how to display pagination link ? sory im noob in php like this one

Comment: @AnggaMovic post is updated. But you need to change URL in for cicle in the end of code. There are just a temp url with only query. Also there are updates in the begining - there are no more dynamic limit support :)